# CMD- DOS Converting Numbers to ASCII

Tags: cmd

So I have a number variable called:
SET /A MAIN_SCORE=1
How do I get Main Score to represent length of the string character X.
So I start off like this:

X

But when I come across the line which states:
SET /A MAIN_SCORE = 3 + MAIN_SCORE
The outcome is:

XXXX

Can you see where I'm getting at? 
Help would be appreciated.
Sorry about the unclear message.

Comment: Do you want a string of X characters, where the length is equal to the value of MAIN_SCORE? If so, then edit your question to say so. If not, then I haven't a clue what you are asking.

Answer (score 0):

```
@ECHO OFF
SETLOCAL
SET xstring=XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
SET mainscore=1
CALL SET xs=%%xstring:~0,%mainscore%%%
ECHO %mainscore% : %xs%
SET /a mainscore=3 + mainscore
CALL SET xs=%%xstring:~0,%mainscore%%%
ECHO %mainscore% : %xs%

GOTO :EOF
```

should do the trick

Comment: So for that script, do I have to define the Maximum range e.g.
XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX
or does it go on forever as it imcrements?

Comment: That's really a matter of practicality. You could for instance set xstring to a string of 8,000+ characters (set up a loop to append xtring to itself a few times, having initialised it to a goodly number.) What would be the practical use of displaying more than a single line? An entire standard screen would be 2080 characters..and there'd be nothing else displayed. Scaling is up to you.